# How much reputation for a question upvote?

Tags: support, votes

In my own question, I get a 2 upvotes so it should be 20 score. But it only shows 10 and 5 per each. Why is that?
Is score 10 is awarded for only answer upvotes?

Comment: For question upvote you get 5 rep for each.

Comment: thanks, thats what I was looking for

Comment: Agreed with Ankit Sharma, and a downvote is -2 if you wanted to know. I learned that the hard way :)

Comment: @natural yeah, downvotes and reputation loss are things that everybody sees rather often and brutal and same as you, I learned the hard way. thanks for your input.appreciate it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I refer you to the [help-center reputation page](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), which confirms that question upvotes give +5 reputation.

Comment: thanks, thats what I was looking for